# How to export an Excel table to latex?

Tags: excel

I have many tables in Ms Excel, and I need to export to a latex file to write an article. I don't want include a figure, I want to copy/import a table from Microsoft Excel.

Then I need an easy method to transform something like this:

```
Linha;Diâmetro, D;Espessurra, t;Área Transversal, At ;
Poço - Manifold;10.75 pol;0.625 pol;19.880 pol²;0.013 m²
Manifold - Costa;22 pol;0.5 pol;33.772 pol²;0.022 m²
```

[image]

In this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rcccc}
    \hline
    Linha & Diâmetro, D & Espessurra, t & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Área Transversal, At } \\
    \hline
    Poço - Manifold & 10.75 pol & 0.625 pol & 19.880 pol² & \textbf{0.013 m²} \\
    Manifold - Costa & 22 pol & 0.5 pol & 33.772 pol² & \textbf{0.022 m²} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/calc2latex-macro-converting-openofficeorg-calc-spreadsheets-latex-tables ...and some human work!

Comment: Also https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex